# Keeping the override of values under control in css

Tags: html, css

I got a table:

```
  <!-- table is in index.html -->
  <table class="printController" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

/*main.css */
table{
    width: 100%;
}

/* tablelist.css */
.printController{
    width: 50%;
}
```

I have specified (in tablelist.css) the width value for the class printColler, which is 50%. 
While in another css file (main.css) I have specified that the width value of a table tag is 100%.

What happens is that the width value gets overwritten by the main.css.

I want to prevent the override of the main.css width value. How to do it?

Comment: That makes no sense. The tablelist.css has a higher precedence than the main so will over rule the main.css rule.

Comment: Write more specific selector

Comment: Look http://jsfiddle.net/znL5A/

Comment: You should read about [CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html). If you put those values into a [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) the class wins so should override the table. Something else is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `!important` keyword:

```
/* tablelist.css */
.printController{
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: nah, he can override using a more specific selector